# Why "dieser" and not "diese"?

Tags: grammatical-case

In the following sentence, why do we write "dieser" and not "diese"? "Kleinstadt" is a feminine noun and the verb "entkommen" suggests that we are dealing with an accusative case?

> Sie ist dieser Kleinstadt beinahe entkommen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that "diese" would be feminine, but it would also be *Nominativ*. Here the word is in *Dativ* and the *Dativ* (*feminine Singular*) of "diese" is "dieser".

Notice the similarity when we replace the *Demonstrativpronomen* with the *Artikel*:

> Sie ist *der* Kleinstadt beinahe entkommen.

"Der" is also masculine (*Nominativ Singular*) but feminine (*Dativ Singular*) as well.

Here are examples of "diese" (feminine) in various declensions:

> *Diese* Kleinstadt ist schön. (Nominativ)
> Die Ansicht *dieser* Kleinstadt ist schön. (Genitiv)
> Sie ist *dieser* Kleinstadt entkommen. (Dativ)
> Ich mag *diese* Kleinstadt. (Akkusativ)

Comment: Why do we use the dative case and not the accusative? The verb "entkommen" suggests movement and movement is associated with the accusative case.

Comment: @GermanStudent: yes, but here we determine from whom/what we escape and this person/thing/circumstance is not moving - the one doing the movement is the one escaping, not what he is escaping from.

Comment: @GermanStudent: - The rule is a bit more subtle than "movement->accusative". It's better to say that accusative indicates the destination of an action, while *entkommen* doesn't have a destination. Also, the rule is about certain, not all, prepositions, and there are no prepositions. In this case it's a verb which happens to always uses a dative object if it uses one at all. There are some verbs and verb-preposition combinations you just have to memorize.